# LDAP - Deleting all records matching a pattern

Tags: linux, ldap, admin

I created thousands of LDAP records using a script, and now I want to delete them. I can script the deletion part too, but it will take a long time to delete more than 200K records.

The DN is like this:

> dn: uid=fev-fvjg6t4x7grcvcn\3DManager,dc=vps1,dc=eng,dc=fireeye,dc=com

There are other records whose DN doesn't have "\3DManager" in the uid. I want to delete all the records which have "\3DManager" in the uid. How do I delete this?

Comment: No. You will have to issue all the necessary delete requests.

Comment: I ended up issuing all the delete requests, one at a time :(